# How can i view an item from a listview that when I click on that item of the listview it will show data on a textblock?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a sqlite datebase and i use a listview to show that datebase up.So i need to know how to implement that when i click an item from the listview some date from the datebase will be shown on a textblock.

Comment: read some blog about select command and where clause

Answer (score 1):

On the textblock bind the Text property to the listview.SelectedItem.SomeProperty

```
<Window
    DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listview"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.SomeProperty, ElementName=listview}"/>
    </Grid>
<Window>
```

Where "SomeProperty" is a column in your database model.

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the selected item's date from item click event of ListView.

```
private void MainListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.ClickedItem as SampleClass;
            var _date = item.ItemDate;
        }
```

Also make IsItemClickEnabled="True" of your Listview. Now you can give text of textblock as _date or assign the datacontext of that textblock as item.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic implementation would be to implement an event handler for the ListView's [`SelectedIndexChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event. And in the event handler just change the textblock text property to the value of the `SelectedItem` property you want to show.

A better approach would to use `XAML` databinding and bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to the `SelectedItem` property you want to show:

Further reading:

[Quickstart: Data binding to controls (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464965.aspx)